# Downloading Large JSON File to local file using Java

Tags: java, json

I'm attempting to download a JSON from the following URL -  http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/companies.js  - to a local file.  I'm using Java 1.7 and the following JSON Libraries - http://www.json.org/java/ - to attempt to make it work.

Here's my code:

```
public static void download(String address, String localFileName) {
            OutputStream out = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            InputStream  in = null;
            try {
                    URL url = new URL(address);
                    out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(localFileName));
                    conn = url.openConnection();
                    in = conn.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int numRead;
                    long numWritten = 0;
                    while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                            out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                            numWritten += numRead;
                            System.out.println(buffer.length);
                            System.out.println(" " + buffer.hashCode());
                    }
                   System.out.println(localFileName + "\t" + numWritten);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    try {
                            if (in != null) {
                                    in.close();
                            }
                            if (out != null) {
                                    out.close();
                            }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    }
            }
    }
```

When I run the code everything seems to work until midway through the loop the program seems to stop and not continue reading the JSON Object.

Does anyone know why this would stop reading?  How could I fix the issue?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "seems to stop".  What exactly happens?

Comment: I can not see anything obvious wrong in the code and just ran it. It worked fine.. After ~40 seconds the whole file was copied.

Comment: When I print out the input stream as it comes it it typically stops midway through...

Here is a partial output of the stream ....


    {"name": "Modem Media",
  "permalink": "modemmedia"},
 {"name": "Digitas",
  "permalink": "digitas"},
 {"name": "Webshots",
  "permalink": "webshots"},
 {"name": "LimeLife",
  "permalink": "limelife"},
 {"name": "Advertising.com",
  "permalink": "advertising-com"},
 {"name": "CTS Media", <----ends here and program does not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public void saveUrl(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
                fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
                {
                        fout.write(data, 0, count);
                }
        }
        finally
        {
                if (in != null)
                        in.close();
                if (fout != null)
                        fout.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why this would stop reading? How could I fix the issue?

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the client-side code.  In the absence of any other evidence on the client side, I'd look at the server-side logs to see if there are any clues there.

IMO, the most likely explanation is one of the following:

- There's a bug in the server-side code that is generating the JSON and it is crashing halfway through.
- The server (or a proxy / reverse proxy) has a timeout on the time allowed for some part of the interaction, and this particular request is taking too long.